# String literals in typescript property map

Tags: typescript, dictionary

I can't seem to access attributes, see below:

```
type ValidAttributes = "FOO" | "BAR" | "BAZ";

interface MyInterface {
  attributes: {
    [s in keyof ValidAttributes]: string;
  };
}

const doSomething = (data: MyInterface): void => {
  const foo = data.attributes.FOO;
  //Error:(10, 31) TS2339: Property 'FOO' does not exist on type '{ toString: string; charAt: string; charCodeAt: string; concat: string; indexOf: string; lastInde...'.

  const bar = data.attributes["BAR"];
  //Error:(13, 15) TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ toString: string; charAt: string; charCodeAt: string; concat: string; indexOf: string; lastInde...' has no index signature.
}
```

I also have a linter which autocorrects the last code into the other format. This could be disabled if it is the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your interface definition:

```
type ValidAttributes = "FOO" | "BAR" | "BAZ";

interface MyInterface {
  attributes: {
    [s in ValidAttributes]: string;
  };
}
```

When you use `keyof` in `ValidAttributes`, you're getting the properties of type String, because `ValidAttributes` is a union of strings. You don't want that, you want the properties to be one of the strings, not the properties of the union of strings, so you just need `s in ValidAttributes`, not `s in keyof ValidAttributes`.

Comment: Thanks. The use of "keyof" was a bummer. ;-)